# Plotly: How to apply different titles for each different subplots?

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

Given that i have the below code from [this link](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/):

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Subplots")
fig.show()
```

The problem in this code is, the `xaxis` and `yaxis` does not have any label. Beside this, the current code applies only one title to all the plots, however I want to apply different ***titles*** to each scatter plot.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> The problem in this code is, the xaxis and yaxis does not have any label.

You can edit any axis by subsetting the structure of your figure:

```
fig['layout']['xaxis']['title']='Label x-axis 1'
```

> Beside this, the current code applies only one title to all the plots

Depending on your plotly version as mentioned by user shaik moeed, you can include `subplot_titles` in your figure definition:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=('Subplot title1',  'Subplot title2'))
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go


# plotly fig setup
fig = make_subplots(rows=1,
                    cols=2,
                    subplot_titles=('Subplot title1',  'Subplot title2')) 

# traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
    row=1, col=2
)

# edit axis labels
fig['layout']['xaxis']['title']='Label x-axis 1'
fig['layout']['xaxis2']['title']='Label x-axis 2'
fig['layout']['yaxis']['title']='Label y-axis 1'
fig['layout']['yaxis2']['title']='Label y-axis 2'

# plot it
fig.show()
```

Comment: Does `x_title` take a dict to tweak x, y position? I'm getting ValueError

Received value: {'text': 'my title', 'y': 0}

    The 'text' property is a string and must be specified as:
      - A string
      - A number that will be converted to a string

Answer (score 10):

Starting with Plotly 4.0.0 you can add master axis titles as x_title respectively y_title:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=2,
                    cols=2,
                    x_title='Your master x-title',
                    y_title='Your master y-title',
                    subplot_titles=('Subplot title1',  'Subplot title2', 
                                    'Subplot title3', 'Subplot title4'))
```

**Sample code:**

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1,
                    cols=2,
                    x_title='Your master x-title',
                    y_title='Your master y-title',
                    subplot_titles=('Subplot title1',  'Subplot title2'))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(title_text="Side By Side Subplots with diffrent sub titles")
fig.show()
```

---

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go


# plotly fig setup
fig = make_subplots(rows=1,
                    cols=2,vertical_spacing=0.09,
                    subplot_titles=('Subplot title1',  'Subplot title2')) 

# traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
    row=1, col=2
)

#fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time_list, y=C_hl0),
      #        row=1, col=1)

fig.update_layout(height=1600, width=1000,
                  title_text="Whatever you want")
for i in range(1,5): 
    fig['layout']['xaxis{}'.format(i)]['title']='Label X axis 1'
    fig['layout']['yaxis{}'.format(i)]['title']='Label X axis 2'

fig.show()

#If you want to save your plot into your local directory

import plotly.io as pio
pio.kaleido.scope.default_format = "png"
fig.write_image(r"C:\fig1.png")
```